# google drive quickstart sample error in android

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I just tried google drive quickstart sample. In the video it seems that its working fine, however when i tried it myself i got this:

[image]

and the error is this:

```
01-09 01:17:23.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1002): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-09 01:17:23.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1002): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.android.gms.common.AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent
01-09 01:17:23.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1002):     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.newChooseAccountIntent(GoogleAccountCredential.java:171)
01-09 01:17:23.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1002):     at com.example.mydrivequickstart.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
01-09 01:17:23.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1002):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-09 01:17:23.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1002):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-09 01:17:23.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1002):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-09 01:17:23.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1002):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-09 01:17:23.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1002):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-09 01:17:23.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1002):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-09 01:17:23.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1002):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-09 01:17:23.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1002):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-09 01:17:23.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1002):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-09 01:17:23.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1002):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-09 01:17:23.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1002):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-09 01:17:23.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1002):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-09 01:17:23.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1002):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-09 01:17:23.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1002):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I followed exactly the instructions. I dloaded na google plugin and add the external jar which is [ggoogle-play-services.jar](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/calendar-preview-android-sample/libs/google-play-services.jar?repo=samples&r=549a58c4b30b111c5f868b73e877a679be48e897) and in google plugin I add the google api drive which is V2. the application name and package name are all the same as in my google api console. I know the nosuchmethoderror as i search it in google before posting this question.However I still dont know why am i getting this because i followed the instructions as it is. I cant figure out why i am getting this error. Any idea? I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. I should not follow the video. The jar he uses is not correct. I import the library from extras folder in android sdk and use it as my lib in my project.

Comment: The jar used in the video comes exactly from the extras folder of the Android SDK

Comment: ow, i see. I search the googel play services and downloaded it. Then use it as my lib. But I had this error and did a little search and found the android sdk which i think is updated than i downloaded.. Sorry